# Update dynamic created components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

### Situation

I have a parent component which renders some child components.
The child component should display information passed from the parent component.

### Context

A battleship game with multiplayer:

The parent component contains a field of 10x10 up to 10x30 buttons (child components). If a button is pressed  a signal with the position of the button get emitted to the api. The api decides if the pressed button needs to change it color.

---

### Problem

By updating the state of the parent the child components props will not be updated if the child is created dynamically.

---

### Solution Attempts

### Dont render Childs dynamically:

Not possible in my case

### Use redux

I consider the child as dump/presentational Component because it only displays information.  Also in my case there are 100-300 Child Components.
[Redux and React](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react)

### Use refs

There are 100-300 Child Components...[Don’t Overuse Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

---

### Question

What should I do? Is there a solution that is not anti-pattern?

Current Code

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      foo: 'BAR'
    }
    this.child=undefined;
  }
  
  componentWillMount(){
    this.child=<Child foo={this.state.foo}/>
  }  
  
  componentDidMount(){
    var that=this
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      that.setState({  //it is just here for demonstration
        foo: 'FOO'
      }) 
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       Is: {this.child}
       Not Dynamic created: <Child foo={this.state.foo}/>
       Actual: <p>{this.state.foo}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>{this.props.foo}</p>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Code with approach from @RaghavGarg and @Clinton Blackburn

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      foo: 'BAR'
    }
    this.child=undefined;
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    var that=this
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      that.setState({  //it is just here for demonstration
        foo: 'FOO'
      }) 
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  renderChild(){
    return <Child foo={this.state.foo} />
  }
  
  render() {
    const child=this.renderChild()
    return (
      <div>
       Is: {child}
       Not Dynamic created: <Child foo={this.state.foo}/>
       Actual: <p>{this.state.foo}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>{this.props.foo}</p>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Clinton said, `componentWillMount` would be only called once. So you are essentially initiating your `this.child` variable, but only updating state, you also need to update the value of the variable.

Since you are just making your dynamic components and saving them in the class instance(like `this.child`). I would recommend you to do the same task in `componentWillUpdate`. So that whenever your state changes, it will be reflected in your dependent variables. But please make sure not to use `setState` inside this lifecycle method.

> `componentWillUpdate()` is invoked just before rendering when new props
>   or state are being received. Use this as an opportunity to perform
>   preparation before an update occurs.

Also, consider using constructor to initiate state and not use `setState` in `componentWillMount`.

> `componentWillMount()` is invoked just before mounting occurs. It is
>   called before `render()`, therefore calling `setState()` synchronously in
>   this method will not trigger an extra rendering. Generally, we
>   recommend using the `constructor()` instead for initializing state.

**Reference:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

### Update after adding context

So now, I am supposing you will be having a DS(maybe an object or a nested array) in the state in which you will be maintaining the status of each box(child component). You can loop over it and provide a unique `key`(maybe like `{row}-{col}`) to every one of them, now you just need to update the state so to reflect the change in the specific child.

**Note:** Using the unique key to every child will enable react internally optimize the re-render and will not re-render the child(using unique key), which is not changed. See below code for reference.

```
this.state = {
  boxes: {
    1: { 
      1:{ status: true, /* more data */ },
      2:{ status: true, /* more data */ },
    },
    2: { 
      1:{ status: true, /* more data */ },
      2:{ status: true, /* more data */ },
    },
    3: { 
      1:{ status: true, /* more data */ },
      2:{ status: true, /* more data */ },
    },
    4: { 
      1:{ status: true, /* more data */ },
      2:{ status: true, /* more data */ },
    }
  }
};

// this will create a 4x2 box, now you will render using above object

// ...somewhere in your render method
{
  Object.keys(this.state.boxes).map(row => (
    <div key={`row-${row}`} className="row">
      {
        Object.keys(this.state.boxes[row]).map(column => (
          <Child 
            key={`box-${row}x${column}`} 
            data={this.state.boxes[row][column]} 
          />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  ))
}
```

Now, whenever you change the `status` of say `2x1` box to `false`, react will only re-render the child with key `box-2x1`.

### Update after [OP comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862802/update-dynamic-created-components/49866136?noredirect=1#comment86790638_49866136)

`shouldComponentUpdate` should be used to decide whether you want to update the component upon the state changes. It's a lifecycle method of React component. By default it returns `true`, but you can return `false` basis on your condition to not update the component. It would definitely help in maintaining the good performance.

**Reference:** [React: Parent component re-renders all children, even those that haven't changed on state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819992/react-parent-component-re-renders-all-children-even-those-that-havent-changed)

Comment: Ok i see your solution is re-rendeingr all compontents. So if one needs an update all 100-300 are rerendering. Wont I face performance issues with that method?

Comment: @Colin, Yeah it would introduce a performance issue. But do you really want to render ~300 child component in a parent which would then all change on parent state update?
Please mention your context or real code, so that I can help you better.

Comment: @Colin, please see the updated answer and share if it solves your problem.

Comment: I tried your code and added a console.log in the render function of the Child component. It got called 100 times so the keys are not helping with the performance issue. I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819992/react-parent-component-re-renders-all-children-even-those-that-havent-changed I implemented the `shouldComponentUpdate` function and now only the right Childs render function get called.

Comment: Damn, I always forget about it. You are totally right about `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method, it would solve the performance issue. Although the `unique key` concept I have told you works after your render function called, it is just a simple optimization done by React, but not better than `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillMount` is only called once when the parent component is inserted into the DOM. It is probably not where you want to create child components that need to be changed after mounting.
See the component lifecycle at https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle.

The simplest solution is to create the child component in the `render()` method. The child component will be re-created when the parent component is updated.