# React: Do children always rerender when the parent component rerenders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

It is to my knowledge that if a parent component rerenders, then all its children will rerender UNLESS they implement `shouldComponentUpdate()`. I [made an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/2x3rmx7rr0) where this doesn't seem to be the true.

I have 3 components: `<DynamicParent/>`, `<StaticParent/>` and `<Child/>`. The `<Parent/>` components are responsible for rendering the `<Child/>` but do so in different ways.

`<StaticParent/>`'s render function statically declares the `<Child/>` before runtime, like so:

```
 <StaticParent>
    <Child />
 </StaticParent>
```

While the `<DynamicParent/>` handles receiving and rendering the `<Child/>` dynamically at runtime, like so:

```
 <DynamicParent>
    { this.props.children }
 </DynamicParent>
```

Both `<DynamicParent/>` and `<StaticParent/>` have `onClick` listeners to change their state and rerender when clicked. I noticed that when clicking `<StaticParent/>` both it and the `<Child/>` are rerendered. But when I click `<DynamicParent/>`, then only the parent and NOT `<Child/>` are rerendered.

`<Child/>` is a functional component without `shouldComponentUpdate()` so I don't understand why it doesn't rerender. Can someone explain why this is to be the case? I can't find anything in the docs related to this use case.

Comment: show more of your code?

Comment: Its in the link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react parent component re-renders all children even those that have not changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819992/react-parent-component-re-renders-all-children-even-those-that-havent-changed)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'll post your actual code for context:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* 
          Clicking this component only logs 
          the parents render function 
        */}
        <DynamicParent>
          <Child />
        </DynamicParent>

        {/* 
          Clicking this component logs both the 
          parents and child render functions 
        */}
        <StaticParent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class DynamicParent extends React.Component {
  state = { x: false };
  render() {
    console.log("DynamicParent");
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.setState({ x: !this.state.x })}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class StaticParent extends React.Component {
  state = { x: false };
  render() {
    console.log("StaticParent");
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.setState({ x: !this.state.x })}>
        <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Child(props) {
  console.log("child");
  return <div>Child Text</div>;
}
```

When you write this code in your Application render:

```
<StaticParent />
```

What's rendered is this:

```
 <div onClick={() => this.setState({ x: !this.state.x })}>
    <Child />
 </div>
```

And in reality, what happens (roughly) is this:

```
function StaticParent(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    "div",
    { onClick: () => this.setState({ x: !this.state.x }) },
    React.createElement(Child, null)
  );
}

React.createElement(StaticParent, null);
```

When you render your DynamicParent like this:

```
<DynamicParent>
    <Child />
</DynamicParent>
```

This is what actually happens (again, roughly speaking)

```
function DynamicParent(props) {
    return React.createElement(
        "div",
        { 
            onClick: () => this.setState({ x: !this.state.x }), 
            children: props.children 
        }
    );
}

React.createElement(
      DynamicParent,
      { children: React.createElement(Child, null) },
);
```

And this is the Child in both cases:

```
function Child(props) {
    return React.createElement("div", props, "Child Text");
}
```

What does this mean? Well, in your StaticParent component you're calling `React.createElement(Child, null)` every time the render method of StaticParent is called. In the DynamicParent case, the Child gets created once and passed as a prop. And since `React.createElement` is a pure function, then it's probably memoized somewhere for performance.

What would make Child's render run again in the DynamicParent case is a change in Child's props. If the parent's state was used as a prop to the Child, for example, that would trigger a re-render in both cases.

I really hope Dan Abramov doesn't show up on the comments to trash this answer, it was a pain to write (but entertaining)

Answer (score 8):

It's mainly cause of you have 2 different "children".

- **this.props.children**
- **`<Child/>`**

They're not the same thing, first one is a `prop` passed down from `Application -> DynamicParent`, while the second one is a `Component` rendered in `StaticParent`, they have separate rendering/life cycles.

Your included example

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* 
          Clicking this component only logs 
          the parents render function 
        */}
        <DynamicParent>
          <Child />
        </DynamicParent>

        {/* 
          Clicking this component logs both the 
          parents and child render functions 
        */}
        <StaticParent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is literally the same as:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // If you want <Child/> to re-render here
    // you need to `setState` for this Application component.
    const childEl = <Child />;
    return (
      <div>
        {/* 
          Clicking this component only logs 
          the parents render function 
        */}
        <DynamicParent>
          {childEl}
        </DynamicParent>

        {/* 
          Clicking this component logs both the 
          parents and child render functions 
        */}
        <StaticParent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a comment to SrThompsons answer: "What would make Child's render run again in the DynamicParent case is a change in Child's props. If the parent's state was used as a prop to the Child, for example, that would trigger a re-render in both cases."
So props or not props passed to child component however it may look will cause a rerender if parent rerenders (so use `React.memo` for a child without props :) )

"Whether you’re implementing your component as a class component that extends React.Component, or as a functional component, the render function is called again whenever the parent container renders again." Please read here for more info, because great article. https://medium.com/free-code-camp/yeah-hooks-are-good-but-have-you-tried-faster-react-components-e698a8db468c"

Answer (score -3):

It will only re-render components that have had a change.  If nothing on the child component has changed, it will not be re-rendered.

Comment: If you look at my example, in the <StaticParent/>, it's <Child/> had no changes at all but it still rendered.