# Why component update lifecycle executes whenever parent's state changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-lifecycle

I have a parent component called 'App' in which a child component is used called
'NewComp'.I have defined componentDidUpdate() lifecycle inside child component,not
in parent component.

Parent component:

```
class App extends Component {

    state = {
      count:0,
    }

    change = () =>{
      this.setState({
        count:this.state.count+1,
      })
    }

    render() {

      return (
        <div>
          <p>Count = {this.state.count}</p>
          <button onClick={this.change}>Add Count</button>
          <NewComp />
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Child Component:

```
export default class NewComp extends Component {

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log('Child component did update');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Child Component</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now every time I change parent state by 'Add Count' button ,the componentDidMount() in child component executes even there is no change in child component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent component is triggered re-render, and in your `NewComp`, `shouldComponentUpdate` alway return true by default, so `NewComp` is triggered re-render as well. You can avoid it by implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` in `NewComp` or use `PureComponent`:

```
export default class NewComp extends PureComponent {

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log('Child component did update');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Child Component</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle method to control when component can update. Usually `componentDidUpdate` is executed when props or state is updated.

Comment: As you said,'componentDidUpdate is executed when props or state is updated',but here no state or props updated

Comment: Please check react documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: As `shouldComponentUpdate` by default send true, so when parent is re-rendered child also updates, Reffering from react docs "shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used."

Answer (score 0):

you can see the below query. Which is similar to yours

[React: Parent component re-renders all children, even those that haven't changed on state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819992/react-parent-component-re-renders-all-children-even-those-that-havent-changed)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Component **Update** life cycle hooks are the hooks which should be used to take some action when there is an update in components **state**, these hooks will definitely execute when there is a state update, that's what they are meant for.

> If you want to execute some logic only when the component gets created please consider using **Creational Life cycle hooks**

Or

> If you want to use `componentDidUpdate` then, please have a check whether your desired **state** or **prop** value is changed and then go ahead

**Creational Life Cycle hooks:**

[image]

**Update Life Cycle hooks:**

[image]