# Why child component's render is called when props did not change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 // Child component
 class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
      console.log("Render of Button called");
      return (
        <button onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
          {this.props.children}
        </button>
      );
    }
  }

 // Parent component
  class ButtonRenderer extends React.Component {
    state = {
      count: 0
    };
    increment() {
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
      });
    }
    render() {
      console.log("Render of ButtonRenderer called.");
      return (
        <div>
          <Button handleClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>Click me</Button>
          <div>Count: {this.state.count}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  function init() {
    var rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    const childElement = <ButtonRenderer />;
    ReactDOM.render(childElement, rootElement);
  }
```

> For every click of the button, state changes in parent component and hence ButtonRenderer.render will be called along with the child component, Button.render. 
>   Why?
>
> I tried all 3 approaches for calling event handlers:
>
> 1. Using inline bind(). As in the above code.
> 2. Class property:

```
... 
increment = () => {
  this.setState({
    count: ++this.state.count
  });
}
...
 <Button handleClick={this.increment}>Click me</Button>
...
```

> 3. Inline arrow function.

```
... 
increment(){
  this.setState({
    count: ++this.state.count
  });
}
...
<Button handleClick={() => {this.increment();}}>Click me</Button>
...
```

> For every click all 3 approaches exected both the render methods.

I expected approach1 and approach2 not to call Button's render method for every click as nothing changed. I expected approach3 to call Button's render method for every click as I am using inline arrow function which will create a new function for every render for ButtonRendered class.

Browser console output for every click of the button:

```
Render of ButtonRenderer called.
Render of Button called
```

My question: Why even approach1 (using bind) and approach2(using class properties) are calling render() method of child component Button when no pros have changed to Button comp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) if you want to avoid unneeded renders:

```js
// Child component
 class Button extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
      console.log("Render of Button called");
      return (
        <button onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
          {this.props.children}
        </button>
      );
    }
  }

 // Parent component
  class ButtonRenderer extends React.Component {
    state = {
      count: 0
    };
    increment = () => {
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
      });
    }
    render() {
      console.log("Render of ButtonRenderer called.");
      return (
        <div>
          <Button handleClick={this.increment}>Click me</Button>
          <div>Count: {this.state.count}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  function init() {
    var rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    const childElement = <ButtonRenderer />;
    ReactDOM.render(childElement, rootElement);
  }
  init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> If a parent component is updated, does React always update all the direct children within that component?
>
> No. React will only re-render a component if shouldComponentUpdate()
>   returns true. By default, that method always returns true to avoid any
>   subtle bugs for newcomers (and as William B pointed out, the DOM won't
>   actually update unless something changed, lowering the impact).
>   [Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819992/react-parent-component-re-renders-all-children-even-those-that-havent-changed)

Actually, by default the child components will always re render unless you explicitly tell then not to. `shouldComponentUpdate` should be implemented here to prevent the unecessary render unless the props value change. Or use `PureComponent`

Answer (score 0):

Solution # 1.

```
    // Parent component
    class ButtonRenderer extends React.Component {
      state = {
        count: 0
      };
      increment = () => {
        this.setState({
          count: ++this.state.count
        });
      }
      render() {
        console.log("Render of ButtonRenderer called.");
        return (
          <div>
            <Button handleClick={this.increment}>Click me</Button>
            <div>Count: {this.state.count}</div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

You Can Avoid Updates by returning false in `shouldComponentUpdate` method. Also you can write business login in it and return `false` or `true` depending on it.

Solution #2.

```
        // Child component
    class Button extends React.PureComponent {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props)
      }
      render() {
        console.log("Render of Button called");
        return (
          <button onClick={this.props.handleClick}>
            {this.props.children}
          </button>
        );
      }
    }

    // Parent component
    class ButtonRenderer extends React.Component {
      state = {
        count: 0
      };
      increment = () => {
        this.setState({
          count: ++this.state.count
        });
      }
      render() {
        console.log("Render of ButtonRenderer called.");
        return (
          <div>
            <Button handleClick={this.increment}>Click me</Button>
            <div>Count: {this.state.count}</div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

When you extend to `React.PureComponent` instead of `React.Component` some lifecycle methods. In this Case this Works.

if you help my answer please consider to upvote