# In React, when a parent component re-renders, isn't it true that the children with unchanged props should not need to re-render?

Tags: reactjs, rerender

I think the fact is that, [when a parent component re-renders in React, in general, all the children components re-render as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819992/react-parent-component-re-renders-all-children-even-those-that-havent-changed).

I did one experiment to confirm:

https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-pine-r16rzi

```
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Time now is {timeNow.toLocaleTimeString()}</div>
      <TheTimeNow /><TheTimeNow />
    </div>
  );
```

This parent component re-renders, and `<TheTimeNow />` has no change in props value (it has none), but it re-renders anyway and shows the updated time.

I think it is not the same to say, that React actually change the DOM, as I think the mechanism is that React use the previous virtual DOM to compare with the new virtual DOM, and update only the **minimal** actual DOM node as on `document.documentElement` as needed.

This can be seen if you use Google Chrome and do Inspect Element on the time statement: only the time portion changes and the other English words stay the same. Compare to this where all the nodes changes if it is plain JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/8sj2ugae/1/ when you do Inspect Element.

However, can't we argue that, if a child is `<Foo />` and since there is no props passed to it, then `<Foo />` really should not have changed, and it is wasteful to call `Foo()`? (if `Foo` is a functional component, or call the `render()` method if it is a class component.)

Now since all children re-renders, that means all their children also get re-rendered. Repeat this rule recursively, that would mean the whole subtree gets re-rendered.

My question is: is it true that they should not need to re-render if their props didn't change, or are there other factors that make them needing a re-render really?

Comment: If parent rerenders children rerender, unless they are optimized using `React.memo` or `shouldComponentUpdate` is used.

Comment: I think I saw "children rerender because to help beginners to avoid any subtle 'not updated' bug"... but then if programmers start using `useMemo()` every where, it is really **tight coupling**. The team has to keep on thinking, oh this component we can use `useMemo()` but the other component cannot and this component now has to because reason XYZ makes it so... it is also very easy to have bugs this way, if the tight coupling itself isn't a problem

Comment: also, `<Foo />` really needs no updating, logically speaking, I think. But it is like React just use a simple rule (and also a dumbed down rule) here, to update everything

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes, there is no need to rerender. But in order to know this we need to compare a new props with a previous props. And this operation is not free.

Also if we do a shallow comparison we are increasing the probability of bugs. Someone might be expecting rerender after a deep props update.

Should `React.memo` be the deault behaviour? Will it improve the performance in most cases? We don't know. There is no evidence for that. More on this in [Mark Erikson's post](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#memoize-everything).

Here is a great article by Dan Abramov: [Before You memo()](https://overreacted.io/before-you-memo/). I consider two points regarding your question:

1. In the future compiler might decide when to memoize a component.
2. Component rendering doesn't mean that all it's children will be rerendered.

Here is an example:

```
const ParentComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

If we update the state children will not be rerendered. React just uses a previous value. Here is an [article by Kent C. Dobbs](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/optimize-react-re-renders) about this optimization technique.

One last thing. `React.memo` and `useMemo` are different. The first one is for component memoization and the second one is a hook for expensive calculations. There are also `shouldComponentUpdate` for class components and `PureComponent` which compare not only props but also a state.

Hopefully the answer and links will shed some light on this topic.